# Configuring sudo to work without password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I'm trying to configure sudo to allow all users to restart apache without having to enter a password.

Security concerns aside, why isn't this working?

I added the line to /etc/sudoers: `%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl`

```
$sudo -l
User aidan may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl
    (ALL) ALL

$sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl
[sudo] password for aidan:
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In my testing on Ubuntu 9.10, this worked.  Care to post your entire sudoers file (redactions allowed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should work fine assuming you put the `%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl` *after* the ALL rule and your goal is to have users of the admin group require a password for sudo for everything but the apache2ctl command.

What you probably want from what you said however is group of users that can start and stop apache, say apachestart.  Then:

```
%apachestart ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl
```

I think you might be able to make it truly everyone by replacing %apachestart with ALL, but I would recommend that even less.

Comment: You only need to logout and login in this setup if you modify the groups of the logged-in user. (Actually, you don't even need to do that; you can use `newgrp` to change groups.)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I had it before the ALL rule. I didn't think it mattered because I could see my new rule in `sudo -l`